# Error Installing Angular 4 using git Bash

Tags: windows, angular, installation

hey i was installing angular and waiting 11 hours and then internet slow down and i got an error

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve/-/resolve- 
1.8.1.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org 
registry.npmjs.org:443 
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network 
settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the 
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07- 
06T21_01_53_610Z-debug.log
```

what should i do??How to complete the installation successfully?

Comment: Can you also share the commands you are using to install angular?

Comment: npm install -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Update node and npm

Run **PowerShell** as ***Administrator***

```
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

Then try angular cli

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: Now internet is good .. but how to complete the installation successuffuly?